# Clear form after using addDoc in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a from where users can enter comments when they click the button the comment gets added to my firestore collection. I just want to clear the form after the button is clicked, by setting my formData to its initial state value, but it doesn't work. The doc gets added to the collection, but the data remains in the input fields. Any ideas?

Thank you

Update: I figured out the problem I had to turn my form into a controlled component then I was able to reset my formData state to blank after pressing the button

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavBar, Footer, Home, About } from "./imports";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  addDoc,
  Timestamp,
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
  const [numberOfVisitors, setnumberOfVistors] = useState([]);
  const [userComments, setUserComments] = useState([]);

  const userCommentsRef = collection(db, "user-comments");

  const addNewComment = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newComment = {
      name: formData.name,
      comment: formData.comment,
      date: Timestamp.now(),
    };
    try {
      await addDoc(userCommentsRef, newComment);
      setFormData([]); //set state back to initial value after adding a doc to clear all the inputs on the form.
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleFormData = (event) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const portfolioStatsRef = collection(db, "portfolio-stats");
    const q = query(portfolioStatsRef);
    const unsubscribeFromEventListener = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const VisitorCountFromDB = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
      setnumberOfVistors(VisitorCountFromDB);
    });

    return () => unsubscribeFromEventListener();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateVisitorCount = async () => {
      try {
        const portfolioStatsDoc = doc(
          db,
          "portfolio-stats",
          numberOfVisitors[0].id
        );
        const updatedFields = {
          visitor_count: numberOfVisitors[0].visitor_count + 1,
        };
        await updateDoc(portfolioStatsDoc, updatedFields);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err + " at updateVisitorCount function");
      }
    };

    if (!numberOfVisitors.length) return;

    let sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionKey");

    if (sessionKey === null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("sessionKey", "randomString");
      updateVisitorCount();
    }
  }, [numberOfVisitors]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(userCommentsRef, orderBy("date", "desc"));
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const userCommentsFromDB = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
      setUserComments(userCommentsFromDB);
    });
  }, [userCommentsRef]);

  const currentNumberOfVisitors = numberOfVisitors.map((visitors) => {
    return (
      <h2 className="p-3 mb-0 bg-dark bg-gradient text-white" key={visitors.id}>
        Number of vistors: {visitors.visitor_count}
      </h2>
    );
  });

  const listOfUserComments = userComments.map((comment) => {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center">
          <h5 className="mb-1">{comment.name}</h5>
          <small>{comment.date.toDate().toDateString()}</small>
        </div>
        <p className="d-flex justify-content-center mb-1">{comment.comment}</p>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden min-vh-100 vh-100">
        <NavBar />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col text-center">
            {numberOfVisitors.length === 0 && (
              <h2 className="p-3 mb-0 bg-dark bg-gradient text-danger">
                Sorry, the Firestore free tier quota has been met for today.
                Please come back tomorrow to see portfilio stats.
              </h2>
            )}
            {currentNumberOfVisitors}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-image">
          <div className="postion-relative">
            <main className="flex-grow-1">
              <div className="container-fluid p-0">
                <Router>
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                  </Routes>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <h4 className="">Comments</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <div className="comments-container">
                        {userComments.length === 0 && (
                          <h4 className="text-danger bg-dark m-1 p-1">
                            Sorry, the Firestore free tier quota has been met
                            for today. Please come back tomorrow to see
                            portfilio comments.
                          </h4>
                        )}
                        {listOfUserComments}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <h4 className="text-dark">Leave a comment</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <form className="comment-form">
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className=" form-control bg-transparent "
                            id="floatingInput"
                            name="name"
                            onChange={handleFormData}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating">
                          <textarea
                            className=" form-control form-textarea-field bg-transparent  mb-1"
                            name="comment"
                            id="floatingTextarea"
                            onChange={handleFormData}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="floatingTextarea">Comment</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="d-grid">
                          <button
                            className="btn btn-primary mb-4"
                            onClick={addNewComment}
                          >
                            Add Comment
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Router>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you add empty obj to setFormData will work, like this : `setFormData({})`

but if it doesn't, you could use loop to empty each key, something like this :

```
let tempFormData;

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(formData)) {tempFormData = { [key] : '' }}

setFormData(tempFormData)
```

Comment: I tried to do the setFormData({}) it didn't work. I have not tried your other suggestion though. Thanks

Comment: Figured out the problem. Please see updated in question